# How RCU reader section is protected from preemption?

Tags: c, algorithm, linux-kernel, preemption, rcu

(From an article on [LWN](http://lwn.net/Articles/262464/))

```
 1 rcu_read_lock();
 2 list_for_each_entry_rcu(p, head, list) {
 3   do_something_with(p->a, p->b, p->c);
 4 }
 5 rcu_read_unlock();
```

The RCU update operation will do synchronize_rcu() in order to assert each CPU switched the context and therefore each RCU-reader has completed it's job. But RCU must rely on reader not being preempted. And indeed, LWN says next:

> Although this simple approach works for kernels in which preemption is
>   disabled across RCU read-side critical sections, in other words, for
>   non-CONFIG_PREEMPT and CONFIG_PREEMPT kernels, it does not work for
>   CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT realtime (-rt) kernels.

I understand preemption is disabled for non-CONFIG_PREEMPT kernels, but why is it OK for **CONFIG_PREEMPT** kernels too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is OK on CONFIG_PREEMPT kernels since care is taken to finish the rcu read critical section before the task is preempted. The scheduler checks if the current task is in a rcu read critical section and if so, it boosts its priority so that it finishes the critical section. For more details see this article: http://lwn.net/Articles/220677/

Answer (score 1):

We need RCU for CONFIG_PREEMPT kernels. If there was no pre-emption or blocking then we wouldn't in this synchronization mess. There are two types of RCU implementations:

```
1) Non-preemptible RCU implementation
2) Preemptible RCU implementation
```

When synchronize_rcu() is invoked on one CPU while other CPUs
are within RCU read-side critical sections, then the
synchronize_rcu() is guaranteed to block until after all the other
CPUs exit their critical sections.  Similarly, if call_rcu() is invoked
on one CPU while other CPUs are within RCU read-side critical
sections, invocation of the corresponding RCU callback is deferred
until after the all the other CPUs exit their critical sections.

In non-preemptible RCU implementations it is illegal to block while in an RCU read-side critical section.
In preemptible RCU implementations (PREEMPT_RCU) in CONFIG_PREEMPT
kernel builds, RCU read-side critical sections may be preempted,
but explicit blocking is illegal.  Finally, in preemptible RCU
implementations in real-time (with -rt patchset) kernel builds, RCU
read-side critical sections may be preempted and they may also block, but
only when acquiring spinlocks that are subject to priority inheritance.

Comment: so why quote says "this simple approach works for kernels in which preemption is disabled across RCU read-side critical sections, in other words, for non-CONFIG_PREEMPT and CONFIG_PREEMPT kernels". Will this approach work when kernel is CONFIG_PREEMPT? Why this quote says preemption is disabled for CONFIG_PREEMPT kernels?